# AWS Signature Version 4: invalid String-to-Sign

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Im am testing AWS SageMaker. I created endpoint, and trying to access it though API (using this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html). But a can not get past authorisation. Response I get is:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST\n/endpoints/xgboost-2019-12-25-08-51-25-561/invocations\n\nhost:runtime.sagemaker.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\nrange:\nx-amz-date:2019-12-26T14:58:11+07:00\n\nhost;range;x-amz-date\n68d422d2479a3c80b36057bcc22fda937f180e70324fb21e7ef4237fef88f22b'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20191226T075811Z\n20191226/eu-west-1/sagemaker/aws4_request\nef356f71401921f6d7ba59a7942c20b47f26ffc154521d53383edddb8fa5c164'\n

The problem is, Canonical String I send are the same:

> POST\n/endpoints/xgboost-2019-12-25-08-51-25-561/invocations\n\nhost:runtime.sagemaker.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\nrange:\nx-amz-date:2019-12-26T14:58:11+07:00\n\nhost;range;x-amz-date\n68d422d2479a3c80b36057bcc22fda937f180e70324fb21e7ef4237fef88f22b

String-to-Sign is different, but it only different with hash of Canonical String, String-to-Sign I send:

> AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20191226T075811Z\n20191226/eu-west-1/sagemaker/aws4_request\nfbd97be5d9bb67d8cea04d8d31517c3b07d8342505cbd08dea3d6dcfd13f0742

All my code:

```
$stamp = time();
$body = json_encode([75,41,1,999,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]);

$canonical = 'POST\n/endpoints/xgboost-2019-12-25-08-51-25-561/invocations\n\nhost:runtime.sagemaker.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\nrange:\nx-amz-date:' . date('c', $stamp) . '\n\nhost;range;x-amz-date\n' . hash('sha256', $body);
$toSign = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n' . date('Ymd\This\Z', ($stamp - (3600 * 7))) . '\n' . date('Ymd', $stamp) . '/eu-west-1/sagemaker/aws4_request\n' . hash('sha256', $canonical);

$key = hash_hmac(
  'sha256',
  hash_hmac(
    'sha256',
    hash_hmac(
      'sha256',
      hash_hmac('sha256', "AWS4" . '<Access Key ID>', date('Ymd', $stamp)),
      'eu-west-1'
    ),
    'sagemaker'
  ),
  'aws4_request'
);

$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $toSign, $key);

$headers = [
  'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<Access Key ID>/' . date('Ymd', $stamp) . '/eu-west-1/sagemaker/aws4_request Signature=' . $signature . ' SignedHeaders=host;range;x-amz-date',
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Accept: application/json',
  'X-Amz-Date: ' . date('c', $stamp)
];
```

Is hash() wrong function to use?